# normalizing a list of very small double numbers (likelihoods)

Tags: c++, probability, logarithm

I am writing an algorithm where, given a model, I compute likelihoods for a list of datasets and then need to normalize (to probability) each one of the likelihood. So something like [0.00043, 0.00004, 0.00321] might be converted to may be like [0.2, 0.03, 0.77]. 
My problem is that the log likelihoods, I am working with, are quite small (for instance, in log space, the values are like -269647.432, -231444.981 etc). In my C++ code, when I try to add two of them (by taking their exponent) I get an answer of "Inf". I tried to add them in log-space [(Summation/Subtraction of log)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Summation.2Fsubtraction), but again stumbled upon the same problem.

Can anybody share his/her expert opinion on this?

Thanks

Comment: Something doesn't smell right.  With those logarithms there'd be an *awful* lot of zeroes.  Are you calculating things right?  Can you show some of your code?

Comment: Can you show us a manageable portion of your code so we can get a better idea of your problem?

Comment: So, to be clear, you need to "normalize" some numbers that are in the range of 6 digits negative, as the logarithmic of the actual value. That would get you a LONG ride with an improbability drive. (hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Improbability_Drive‎). As John says, this seems wrong... These numbers are so small that the chances of hitting one atom when playing electron golf through the universe is more likely.

Comment: The likelihoods are computed for a phylogenetic tree given a set of protein sequences at the leaves. Since there are exponential number of trees for an n-leaf unrooted tree, finding such low number for likelihoods isn't unexpected (consider 500 leaves binary tree with each leaf consisting of 1000+ protein characters). 


Even if we talk about log likelihoods around -2k to -3k, can we find some reasonable estimate?

Comment: Ok, I'm actually familiar with that type of tree (but I don't know much about the underlying math). However, if the probability in this case is the "likelyhood of being related", I think once you get to the negative thousands in log, we're talking "no chance", whatever they are. So normalize everything beyond a certain point to 0.

Comment: I think the numbers calculated here are only proportionate to the actual likelihoods, so don't be confused by the small sizes. There is a divisor that is the same for all of them, and therefore is normally not calculated, but that is also likely to be very small in this sort of situation.

Comment: Nothing strange about those log-likelihood values at all - in fact they look typical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the likelihoods have been calculated correctly, you could divide each of them by the largest likelihood. That can be done in logarithm form by subtracting the largest log-likelihood from each log-likelihood.

You can then convert out of logarithm space. The largest will be 1.0, because its normalized log is 0. The smaller ones will each be between 0 and 1.0, and represented as a fraction of the largest.

Comment: That, of course, assumes that the largest and smallest numbers are within a reasonable range of each other. In the example numbers given, the difference is roughly 34000 - which is still a long way outside regular floating point number's range, even if it's log2 and using 80-bit long double, which has an exponent of 2^+/-16383.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Those big ratios trouble me more than the small size. There is a normalizing constant in Bayes' equation that is often not calculated, because it is the same for all cases. All being small could be due to that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try it and let you know

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I agree the ratios are concerning, and definitely worth looking into, but it may just be that the model is very confident that the smaller ones have infinitesimal probability.

Answer (score 3):

This is standard procedure. Numerically stable Matlab code:

```
LL = [ . . . ];  % vector of log-likelihoods
M = max(LL);
LL = LL - M;
L = exp(LL);
L = L ./ sum(L);
```